# Is out of bounds access safe in python? Is it bad form?

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

```
> [1, 2, 3][1:int(1e9)]
[2, 3]
```

Coming from C background the above code gives me a mini heart attack. But it seems to work. Is it guaranteed to work in any `python3`? Is it as efficient as `> [1, 2, 3][1:int(2)]`? Is it considered bad form as in 'prefer to use anything else before relying on this behavior'?

---

OK, I've probably described the problem badly. This is my code. The last access is out of bonds most of the time. Is that fine?

```
def cut(b: bytes, max: int) -> [bytes]:
    '''Chop into pieces no longer than max bytes.'''
    return [b[i:i+max] for i in range(0, len(b), max)]
```

Comment: It's mostly considered "why would you not just use `[1:]`?" As for why it's safe, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations, note 4. _By definition_ a value greater than `len(s)` is set to `len(s)` as part of resolving the slice.

Comment: for your update: yes, that's fine, but you're not guaranteed same sized slices. Whether that's a problem is mostly up to you and what downstream code you've written.

Comment: Thanks! Your 2 comments are already an answer so if You would copy-paste them we could resolve the thread. Please also add one sentence on is there a glaringly simpler solution to what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: If you search SO for chunking up a list in python, you'll find a million post that all have "this is fine" as answer, so honestly based on your edit, this is more of a duplicate than anything else.

Comment: For example: [How do I split a list into equally-sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-i-split-a-list-into-equally-sized-chunks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is an intended behavior of Python's slice.

Excerpt from Python's official [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html):

> out of range slice indexes are handled gracefully when used
> for slicing:
>
> ```
> >>> word[4:42]
> 'on'
> >>> word[42:]
> ''
> ```